# Is RAW Binding a death sentence?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

The *Chaining* and *Hedged prison* variants of [Binding](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/binding.htm) restrict the subject's movement in quite an extreme way, and prevent other creatures from approaching it. Unlike the other variants, however, they do *not* remove the need for food, water and air. Does that mean that their subject is practically guaranteed to die of hunger or thirst unless the caster of Binding actively and continuously takes action to prevent that? (Assuming a subject which needs to eat and drink, of course).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes...** If nobody tries to save them.

With *Chaining* creatures can approach if the creature approaching passes a will save.
With *Hedging* it appears that they are just trapped permanently and will die unless they don't need to breathe or eat, which a number of creatures are immune to. The phrase

> from which it cannot wander by any means.

worries me however, given its vagueness. Allies can probably still force the creature to move and if the creature is capable of using spells, anti-magic field works, as does sending a message to someone to get the word out that you need help.

Given that this spell is higher level than *Flesh to Stone*, *Insanity* and *Finger of Death*, combined with being both *Mind-Affecting* (a tag that applies to oh-so-many creatures at this level) and the possibility of being found using it doesn't make sense from an optimisation point of view; but it would *probably* cause their death if nobody was looking to save them.

Comment: Good catch, missed that.

Comment: Spell descriptions says that it cannot be dispelled by dispel magic.

Answer (score 6):

It’s an 8th-level mind-affecting, Will-negates compulsion.
**It’s not a death sentence, because it will never work on anyone who cares.**

*Protection from evil* arguably blocks the effect. That’s a first level spell. Even if not, *mind blank* **definitely** does, for 24 hours, at the same spell level (and it blocks far more dangerous effects, to boot). All constructs, oozes, plants, and undead have *always* been immune to it. Everyone else has to make sure that they *get* immunity to it, because it’s relatively easy to do and the consequences for allowing mind-affecting spells to stick can be worse than death.

For that matter, *slay living* is a 5th-level spell, and has far fewer descriptors that you can be protected against (requiring *death ward* rather than *protection from evil*), and that doesn’t require burning 500(HD+1) gp and a specially-made statuette.

But anyway, yes, someone who is actually dumb enough to have one of these *bindings* placed on him will die from dehydration.

Comment: Your comments about "everyone should be immune or they're dumb" are off-topic and should probably be re-phrased to "there are ample ways to negate."

Comment: @DougM There aren’t just ample ways to negate. There are ample ways to negate, that also negate a whole smorgasbord of other, more dangerous things, and negating is so easy and leaving yourself so vulnerable that sooner-or-later *everyone* should be immune.